# How to call a function after getting model from database?

Tags: laravel

i'm getting model using this code:

```
$user = \App\Http\Models\User::where('id', $id)->with('services')->get();
```

and i want to call this function for example

```
$user->getServiceList(); //this metod gets ALL services, not hasMany
```

but it causes an error 
**Method getServiceList does not exist**

Comment: you dont have a Model, you have a Collection that potentially has many Model instances in it .... `get` always returns a Collection (many) .. if you want one, use `first`

Comment: You can just `$user = User::find($id);` to look for a user by his ID.

Also, where did you declare the function `getServiceList`?

Answer (score 2):

`get()` loads a collection, so you need to iterate over it to get objects:

```
$users = \App\Http\Models\User::where('id', $id)->with('services')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->getServiceList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to use [find](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method if you are searching by user id:

```
 $user = \App\Http\Models\User::with('Service')->find($id);

 $user->getServiceList();
```